# Skip Running Application Popup Check

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, uninstallation, silent-installer

I have created a WIX Install which installs a console application as background app.
When we try to uninstall program then it shows that following popup application should be closed and fail to close.

[image]
[image]

I have wrote custom action to close the running application which runs after these popup shows.

**Is their any way we can bypass this running application check OR run custom action before it check for running apps ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is their any way we can bypass this running application check?

try setting MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL=Disable property in Msi property table.

> run custom action before it check for running apps?

By the time above FileInUse dialog appears, check the msi log without closing the popup. Find the last standard custom action which displaying this dialog. Once you get it, schedule your custom action before it in InstallExecuteSequence table..

Comment: Thanks @Viv,  <Property Id="MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL" Value='Disable'/>
worked for me.